# Server Push vs Server pull in IIS

Tags: chat

I was thinking of building a chat application in ASP .NET. I was thinking of either using push or pull. I have found that pull is more scalable than push. But does any body know if the web chat messenger like gtalk, yahoo etc use pull or push ?.

Thanks.

Comment: Push as in something comet-ish? (Web client),  or will there be an IM client with your own protocol?

Comment: @Prashant: he was talking about doing a web application doing some IM, like the gtalk portlet on Gmail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gmail and such are using comet. This is a push architecture.

There is a nice article on [ajaxian](http://ajaxian.com/archives/comet-a-new-approach-to-ajax-applications) describing how comet works, this technique is used to push data from the server to the client.

But I am really looking forward the [WebSocket](http://www.w3.org/TR/2009/WD-websockets-20091029/), I think it's gonna make a lot of things more easy.

Comment: actually push scale better then pull, there is only one connection by user so it's easy to calculate the number of server you need. Simply you need a webserver adapted to that, Apache is creating process for each bunch of client, while some other webserver just wait for data on each socket.

Comment: comet have also a bunch of special webserver for such applications

Comment: I don't think IIS is adapted for a comet architecture

Comment: Don't know much about comet on IIS, but last I read somewhere there is this thing called WebSync that supposedly do comet for IIS